# Finding Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having some trouble finding the subgroups of direct product groups, in the form of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$. How does one go about finding these subgroups? For instance, how do I find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Well for starters, there are those of the form $H \times K$, where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\mathbb Z_m$. However not all subgroups are of that form.

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ have coprime orders then all subgroups of $H \times K$ are direct products of subgroups of $H$ and of $K$. This enables you to reduce to the prime power case. So in this case it would be sufficient to find the subgroups of $C_2 \times C_4$, and for that you could subdivide by order.